# Ruby on Rails SQLite3::NotADatabaseException (file is encrypted or is not a database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite3-ruby, encryption

I am afraid something really bad happened while I was messing around with my RAILS app. It was working fine, and I am not sure what I did, but I get the following error:

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-30 02:20:15 -0500
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Completed   in 18ms

SQLite3::NotADatabaseException (file is encrypted or is not a database):
  app/models/user.rb:81:in `authenticate_with_salt'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:79:in`user_from_remember_token'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:18:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in`signed_in?'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:9:in `home'

Rendered /Users/ikylim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/ikylim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered /Users/ikylim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (5.2ms)

Anybody experience this? I really can't figure this out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem by running:

$ rake db:reset

This deleted everything in the database that I had saved previously, but at least my app works again to work with. I am still unsure why this happened out of the blue, so hopefully somebody could provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be due to the permissions, you are using salt & permissions on your database.sqlite3 is messed up

Comment: Thanks Anup, but I didn't touch any of those things and they were working properly before. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: have u entered the password for database in database.sqlite3?